# Does Gazebo have a topic to which we can publish models to be spawned into the world?

Tags: gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I remember few years back when I was learning Gazebo I saw something about some factory topic to which you would publish when you wanted to spawn or delete a model to/from your world. But now I am unable to find anything about it. Did I just misinterpreted something? Does any mechanism as such exists in gazebo?

We want to run tests in the simulation and create different worlds for each case without turning the simulation off and loading it again. I don't think you can load the whole different world from description during the simulation, so I'm looking for a way to delete all the models from previous test case and spawn all the models for the next test case. Is there any best practice?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25418/does-gazebo-have-a-topic-to-which-we-can-publish-models-to-be-spawned-into-the-world?/) by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 755 on 2020-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It exists the `/gazebo/server/control` topic, which has an open_filename field, but the feature for [dynamically loading a new world is not implemented](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/blob/gazebo11/gazebo/Server.cc#L752).

For loading models, you have the `~/factory` topic. Examples are [here](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/tree/gazebo11/examples/plugins/factory).

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) with karma: 833 on 2020-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0